# Second item in a nested row always adds extra margins, throwing off the layout

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm working with Foundation 5, none of my own custom styles. I'm linking, in order, `app.css`, `modernizr.js`, jQuery, Fastclick, and `foundation.min.js`.

I have followed instructions in my tutorial ("Lynda: Up and Running With Foundation") and on the Zurb website for creating a nested row, but there's a problem: the last cell in the row always jumps itself over by a small amount, throwing off not just the text flow but the entire page layout. On mobile devices, this small nudge means that the page can be swiped side to side.

[Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZomK.png).

My HTML is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns panel callout">
        <h2>Our Mission</h2>
         ...text...
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <h3>We're Awesome.</h3>
        text
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <h3>Buy From Us!</h3>
        text
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <h3>Good Products?</h3>
            text
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <h3>"Licensed"</h3>
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What have I done wrong? I can't see any information on Google or StackOverflow about this, I've gone over the code carefully, I've torn it down and rewritten it from scratch following code samples... I just don't get what I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, although using large-3 columns approximates the correct output you need a little bit different structure. There are many ways to do things, but the thing to remember, is that if you are using a grid or a nested grid, all the columns must add up to 12 columns total. In your case you have a nested grid that adds up to 6. This will give you inconsistant output unless you intent for part of the column to be empty. In that case you can use the .end presentational class to force it to float left.

Here is a set of nested grids that approximates what I think you are going for.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns panel callout">
    <h2>Our Mission</h2>
    text
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <h3>We're Awesome.</h3>
        text
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <h3>Buy From Us!</h3>
        text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <h3>Good Products?</h3>
        text
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <h3>"Licensed"</h3>
        text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This works, and teaches me more about how to use Foundation. Thanks a lot for your help!